# CORS Issue Ionic 4, WordPress 5.2 and JWT Authentication

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jwt, ionic4, wordpress-rest-api

I am using Angular 6 and Ionic 4 with Wordpress 5.2 and JWT Authentication to access an API in wp-json. I was sure to enable CORS according to JWT Authentication and also custom CORS headers in Theme function but I am still receiving the error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://oc.xxxx.com/wp-json/erp/v1/crm/contacts' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

The custom CORS header in my theme function is as follows,

```html
function my_customize_rest_cors() {
  remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
  add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link', false );
    return $value;
  } );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_customize_rest_cors', 15 );
```

and on my Ionic app, the code to call the API content is as follows,

```html
getContact() {
    var service = this;
    let url = service.appConfig.Shop_URL + "/wp-json/erp/v1/crm/contacts";
    url = this.initUrl(url, '');
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + service.userService.token);
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      service.http.get(url, { headers: headers }).pipe(map(res => res.json())).subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
          service.cachedData = data;
          resolve(service.cachedData);
        }
        else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

What did I miss that cause the CORS blocking? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer i am having the exact same problem , thanks in advance

Comment: @TahaAmineZeghbib Yes. Added the answer in the snippet. Have a check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
function my_customize_rest_cors() {
  remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
  add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link', false );
    return $value;
  } );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_customize_rest_cors', 15 );

function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link', false );
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

Use either one of the functions to check

Comment: We were having general CORS issues (not specifically for JWT) trying to access the REST API from ionic ios physical devices.

All I was looking to do was inject the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header.  I used the first function from the above snippet and removed all the other header changes and it sorted my issue!

Comment: Ever since yesterday I'm experiencing this issue on building my app, localhost and previous versions are fine. Neither suggested solution works.

Answer (score 0):

To make the authentication service work, you need to install the [wp-api-jwt-auth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin, which allows you to generate an authentication token.

Carefully follow all installation and setup instructions provided on the [plugin information page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/).

In general, you need to do the following:

1 - Install the [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin.

[image: JWT Authentication for WP REST API]

2 - Edit the `.htaccess` file to enable the HTTP Authorization Header.
(Most of the shared hosting has this disabled by default.)

After editing the .htaccess file for the JWT plugin, mine now looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

3 - Add an **secret key** and enable the **CORS Support** adding two constants (`JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY`, `JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE`) to the `wp-config.php` file.

```
/**
 * WordPress JWT Authentication for WP REST API
 *
 * You can generate secret keys using the WordPress.org secret-key service at:
 * https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
 */
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secret-key');
define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
```

4 - And finally, activate the plugin in wp-admin.